# How many entries are stored inside the iPhone adress book?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible to know the number of entries stored inside the iOS address book programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

Use `ABAddressBookGetPersonCount` to count total contacts, Like :-

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate( );
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople( addressBook );
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount( addressBook );

for ( int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++ )
{
     ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i );
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
CFIndex peopleCount = CFArrayGetCount(people);
CFArrayRef groups = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllGroups(addressBook);
CFIndex groupsCount = CFArrayGetCount(groups);
```

For more information please see the [Address Book Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH1-SW1).